# Published my MVC 5 site used to be webforms 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I had a website in ASP.Net 4.5 Webforms on DiscountASP.Net since approx. last April. I converted my website to MVC 5. I basically re wrote it from scratch. When I click on one of the links, it redirect me to a webpage that says [To Parent Directory] and list some directories from my previous project (4.5 webforms).

I tried rebuilding the project and publishing it again and I still have the issue. I am not sure what is wrong.

Can someone try clicking on the one of the two Practice Areas links on this website: www.attorneybeaulac.com and see what might cause the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no Index.aspx under /PracticeAreas

The pages that work have views /PracticeAreas/FamilyLaw -> FamilyLaw.aspx

Things to check:

- Make sure to properly prep the server for MVC 5.
- Make sure .NET 4.5 is installed since that is the framework you are building with VS 2013 (and is required for the latest)
- Check that you've run regiis_aspnet -ir to register .NET 4.5
- Make sure to deploy your dependencies, all of the MVC and Razor assemblies to your site bin directory.
- Make sure you have site configured as a .NET 4 site.
- Make sure your web/mvc/razor references have copy local set to true
- Clean the deployment destination and deploy fresh

Comment: I am not sure I follow. It is an MVC 5 website it does not use .aspx logic.

Comment: Well I was just observing. You need to create a view of some sort, for index whether it is razor or aspx.

Comment: Are you saying that your new site has all .cshtml files and the directory I'm seeing is old files?

Comment: I actually do have an Index.cshtml files under Practice Areas. I am thinking that it is caching or something from my old website.

Comment: Did you deploy MVC assemblies? What steps did you take to setup MVC support?

Comment: I am pretty new to Microsoft development. All I did was deploy it from VS 2013. Build--Publish. All the other links are working. I know that I had a Practice Areas folder in both projects.

Comment: MVC support is not builtin to the server. It is on your PC because you have Visual Studio 2013, but you need to deploy the MVC assemblies (System.Web.MVC.dll, System.Web.Razor.dll, and others).

Comment: I'll update my answer with directions / link for MVC installation. It is possible to install the MVC package on the server from Microsoft, but nowadays most people "bin deploy" which means they deploy the MVC libs with the app.

Comment: I created a Main.cshtml and I am using that instead of the Index.cshtml under the Views\PracticeAreas folder and it works. I do not like that work around and I wish I could pin point what I did wrong but oh well.

Comment: The fact that you are missing your views indicates you didn't deploy the site correctly. You should have a .cshtml file for every view.

Comment: Totally possible, but keep in mind it is the only view that did not work. All the others worked. When you click on the view that is broken, why is it pointing to .aspx files from my old site??? Those files are not in my new website, I created it from scratch! I just look at the control panel and the root directory is still the old one. I am going to wait and see if that fixes itself. Regardless, I appreciate your time and I will look at your answer.

Comment: Update: In web Deploy I checked the option to Remove additional files at destination and it fixed the issue.